# pass state to child views in Xamarin VisualStateManager

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some nested ContentViews. Lets say it's look like this:

```
MasterView    
- TwoRowView
--- TitleView
----- TitleLabel
----- DateLabel
----- Icon
--- ContentView
----- TwoRowView
------- DetailTitleView
------- DetailBodyView
- TwoRowView
--- [...]
```

And,in some moment, in `TwoRowView` code behind, I'm setting `TitleView` state via `VisualStateManager.GoToState([TitleView],[stateName])` (it's pseudcode, it's don't look like this with those 
square bracket in reality, I just don't want to confuse you with irrelevant code and variables names ;) ) to some state, let name it "Expanded"
But what i want to do from that point, is to actually set states of `TitleLabel` to this state.

What is best way to pass `VisualStateManager` state to child views, when it was setted in parent view? Or maybe i should take totally different approach?

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, i think use `VisualStateManager.GoToState` is a good choice.
You just need to focus on when to send the status to the control in you back code.such as following code, create a method `GoToState` pass the statue to the view or control.

```
public partial class VsmValidationPage : ContentPage
{
public VsmValidationPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    GoToState(false);
}

void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(args.NewTextValue, @"^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$");
    GoToState(isValid);
}

void GoToState(bool isValid)
{
    string visualState = isValid ? "Valid" : "Invalid";
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(helpLabel, visualState);
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(submitButton, visualState);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but problem is a bit more complicated. In your example code, Something internally detectable (Text Change) lead to style changing. In my case, change comes from outside - Parent ContentView is setting state in child view, and those child view need to pass that state change to it's children.

Comment: Could you share a demo about your issue?